# NodeJS Mongoose - Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to print out to the console the name of a Team in my database, here is the code:

```
var Team = require('../schemas/Team').Model;
app.get('/match', function(req, res) {
    var key = 1359407087999; // Team Key
    Team.findByKey(key, function(err, team) {
        util.log(team);
        if (err) {
            util.log("Error occured");
        }
        if (!team) { 
            util.log("The team does not exist");
        } else {
            res.send("Found team: " + team.name);
        }
    });
});
```

The code gets the Team successfully where `util.log(team)` is. It prints this to the console:

```
{
    __v: 0,
    _id: 5106e7ef9afe3a430e000007,
    name: 'Team Name',
    key: 1359407087999 
}
```

This also works when sending it to the web page as well.

But when I try to send the Team's name to the web page, I get the following output with the `res.send` method => `Found team: undefined`...And when I try to output `team.name` instead of `team` to the console, I get the error `Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined`

Here is my Team mongoose schema as well:

```
var Team = new Schema({
    'key' : {
        unique : true,
        type : Number,
        default: getId
    },
    'name' : { type : String,
        validate : [validatePresenceOf, 'Team name is required'],
        index : { unique : true }
    }
});

Team.statics.findByKey = function(key, cb){
    return this.find({'key' : key}, cb);
};

module.exports.Schema = Team;
module.exports.Model = mongoose.model('Team', Team);
```

show team

```
app.get('/show/team/:key', function(req, res){
    util.log('Serving request for url[GET] ' + req.route.path);
    Team.findByKey(req.params.key, function(err, teamData){
        util.log(teamData[0]);
        if (!err && teamData) {
            teamData = teamData[0];
            res.json({
                'retStatus' : 'success',
                'teamData' : teamData
            });
        } else {
            util.log('Error in fetching Team by key : ' + req.params.key);
            res.json({
                'retStatus' : 'failure',
                'msg' : 'Error in fetching Team by key ' + req.params.key
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name is unique, so you should use `findOne` instead of `find`.

```
Team.statics.findByKey = function(key, cb){
  return this.findOne({'key' : key}, cb);
};
```

Comment: This has now broken my other code which I have put in the original post, do you have any idea why? With find it works but with findOne it now doesn't work...

Comment: remove the two occurance of [0].

Comment: find returns an array of documents (teams in your case), findOne return an object.